# Gradle dependencies with SonarQube

Tags: android, gradle, sonarqube

I have a multi module project with Android Studio and I want to get it work with Sonarqube 5.1.

When I run:

```
gradlew sonarqube
```

I'm getting "class not found" errors, related to dependency jars. For example:

```
....
12:56:50.308 ERROR - Class not found: com.google.protobuf.ProtocolMessageEnum
12:56:50.309 ERROR - Class not found: com.google.protobuf.Internal
....
```

How can I add gradle dependencies without adding the absolute path for each dependency? Isn't it automatic?

This is my configuration

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0'
}

sonarqube  {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.projectName', 'myApp'
        property 'sonar.java.binaries', file('build/intermediates/classes/debug')
        property 'sonar.java.libraries','C:/Programs/Android/sdk/platforms/android-22/android.jar'  
    }
}
```

And this works:

```
property 'sonar.java.libraries','C:/Programs/Android/sdk/platforms/android-22/android.jar, PATH/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/a10732c76bfacdbd633a7eb0f7968b1059a65dfa/*.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If absolute paths are working for you may try to build the string like this:

```
def sonarLibraries = buildscript.configurations.classpath.join(",")
property 'sonar.libraries', sonarLibraries
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. In my case it was: configurations.compile.join(",")